# The equivalent of 'objective' from 'optimize' in 'uniroot' in R?

Tags: r, optimization

I was wondering what is the equivalent of 'objective' outputted by 'optimize' in the list of values outputted by 'uniroot' in R?

An example:

```
uniroot(function(x) cos(x) - x, lower = -pi, upper = pi)

optimize(function(x) (cos(x) - x)^2, lower = -pi, upper = pi)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wouldn't necessarily be an "equivalent", since the minimum wouldn't always be 0, but in the case you offer where the minimization is to a numerical target of 0, the best match would be $ f.root `num 1.38e-06$ f.root` which is what the expression evaluates to at the final iteration.